# How to approach Machine Learning problems with dynamically sized input collection?

Tags: machine-learning, relational-database, neural-network, data-mining, feature-extraction

I'm approaching a problem trying to classify a data sample as good or bad quality with machine learning.

The data sample is stored in a relational database. A sample contains the attributes id, name, number of up-votes (for good/bad quality indication), number of comments, etc. Also there is a table that has items with foreign keys pointing to a data sample id. The items contain a weight and a name. All items together pointing to a data sample characterizes the data sample, which typically could help classify the data sample. The problem is, that the number of items pointing to one foreign key is different for different samples.

I want to feed the Machine Learning input, of e.g. a neural network, with the items that point to a specific data sample. The problem is that I don't know the number of items, so I don't know how many input nodes I want.

Q1) Is it possible to use neural networks when the input dimension is dynamic? If so, how?

Q2) Are there any best practices for feeding a network with a list of tuples, when the length of the list is unknown?

Q3) Are there any best practices for applying machine learning to relational databases?

Answer (score 5):

There's a field of machine learning called Inductive Logic Programming that deals exclusively with relational data. In your case, if you wish to use a neural network, you would want to transform your relational data set to a propositional data set (single table) - i.e., a table with a fixed number of attributes that can be fed into a neural network or any other propositional learner. These techniques usually construct so-called first-order features, which capture the data from secondary tables. Further, you need to do this only for inducing your learner - once you have the features and the learner, you can evaluate these features for new data points on-the-fly.

Here's an [overview paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.1.4738) of some techniques that can be used for such a problem. If you have any further questions, ask away.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for good reading up on basic ILP? I'm quite the newbie on ML in general but still interested in the subject so I want to learn it better.

Comment: You can find a good intro in [Lavrac&Dzeroski](http://www-ai.ijs.si/SasoDzeroski/ILPBook/), it's a bit dated, but it's available for free online. For a more up-to-date reading try [De Raedt](http://books.google.si/books/about/Logical_and_Relational_Learning.html?id=0EYVINC1paAC&redir_esc=y).

Answer (score 2):

Neural networks are not designed to work with dynamically sized input. Very few machine learning methods are, they typically assume constant dimensionality. I think the simplest way to deal with this is to compute summary statistics over your variable-sized instances, for example if you have an arbitrary number of inputs, calculate the mean (and variance, and whatever else you like) of these inputs, which will be of fixed dimension, if your heart is set on using neural nets.

There is a class of models which are suited to what you want to do: [Bayesian nonparametrics](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/talks/uai05tutorial-b.pdf). This is a particularly elegant class of models which has the capacity to grow to infinite size, but always uses a finite number of parameters to explain a finite amount of data. Model updates are well-defined in the presence of increasing amounts of data (the number of parameters in the models simply increase as much as needed to accommodate them).

However, there are two big caveats:

1. These models are hard. If you don't have a decent background in machine learning and statistics there may be considerable pickup time
2. Inference in infinite models is intractable. This is usually handled using MCMC methods, which are fairly computationally intensive. Although there have been recent advances in [variational nonparametrics](http://www.princeton.edu/~sjgershm/GershmanHoffmanBlei12.pdf), this is still a new area of research and you certainly won't find implementations of this stuff for a wide range of models.

Comment: What if I say I know the input dimension, but if it has to be fixed it is very large? About 3000 inputs. Is it then possible to use neural networks, or is there too many inputs for it to efficiently train on a dataset of approx 25k data instances?

Comment: I suspect that's possible, but it would depend in part on what sort of NN you're using. If it's a simple architecture I wouldn't imagine you'd have any trouble: if you're looking at a deep belief net it's going to be more tricky!

Comment: Okey, thanks for answersing again! :)

Do you have any other suggestions for how to train using previous data and classify quality of new data?

I have just basic knowledge about ML and I'm doing a project where I'd like to apply the ML alg on relational datatables. This particular problem is related to a simple many-to-many relation.

Comment: I don't know if there's anything particular about the relational database---you're going to want to extract instances from it and represent them in some feature space as with all machine learning. There are many possible methods: SVMs, random forests, Bayesian methods, etc are all perfectly plausible. Take a look at an introductory ML book (for example, Tom Mitchell's Machine Learning)

Comment: Okey. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer to all questions, but maybe this will help:

Q1) You could try using some method of [dimensionality reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_reduction), such as [principal component analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) (PCA), to map all your input objects into a common dimension. To do this, you'd have to pick all data points with length N and use only those to learn a map from dimension N to dimension M.

Example: suppose that you have inputs which can have size 3, 4, and 5. You'll need to learn a map from size 5 to size 3, which you can learn using all your points which have size 5, and a map from size 4 to size 3, which you can learn using all your points which have size 4.

I do not expect this to work very well, though.

Q2) Should not be a problem anymore if Q1 is solved.

Q3) I'm speculating on this one, but maybe you could map the database to a graph, and use the multitude of algorithms which are out there for learning in graphs?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there are no well known classification methods that work directly on dynamically sized input collections. Dimensionality reduction works by reducing high dimensional, but fixed data to lower dimensions, so it really doesn't seem like what you need.

One way in which this is handled in machine learning for binary classification (which seems is the problem you're interested in) is by building histograms. For example you can categorize text (of varying length) by building histograms of the words that appear in the text. Several extensions have been presented, histograms of  bi-grams, n-grams but they build on the same idea.

Another type of idea is structured prediction, a good example of which is when you have a sentence and you need to determine for each word, what part of speech it is, in this type of setup each word has a label, and the interaction between labels is very important. Well understood method for this type of problem are [Latent Structural SVM](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~cnyu/latentssvm/), [CRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_random_field), and [Max Margin Markov Network](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDgQFjAA&url=http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips16/NIPS2003_AA04.pdf&ei=t9vAUIH2NKm20QGV9YGACw&usg=AFQjCNHzW9Wc68rib1oO9mV71CtHXm7AWg&sig2=nyz53sKhTuQg7n5HFKwtuw)

Answer (score 1):

My apologies for adding a second answer, but it is substantially different from my first one.

One possibility which could work is to do the following: suppose that your input can have size 3, 4 or 5. You make your neural-network have 5 input nodes (the maximum size of your input). Then, if a point with size 3 appears, you provide its values on the first 3 nodes, and provide a dummy value on the remaining nodes.

Let's discuss a concrete example: suppose that your input are points in R^3, R^4 or R^5, and they are binary: they can take values 0 or 1 at each entry. If a point (0,1,0,0,1) appears, you just feed those values into the 5 input nodes of the network. If a point (0,1,1) appears, you feed (0,1,1,-1,-1) to the network, where here -1 is the dummy value. This ensures that you are giving your network the information that "the last two nodes are special".

In a linear classifier, dummy values are very dangerous; however, since a neural-network is not linear, it can (in principle) learn any function, as long as you give it the information it needs and have enough training data to feed it.